# Não somos passarinhos! Utilização do termo 'nidificação' na página de ajuda

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Encontrei o termo *nidificação* na página de [ajuda sobre formatação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help/), nas seções sobre [listas avançadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#advanced-lists), ["aspas avançadas"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#advanced-blockquotes) (deveria ser "citações", não "aspas") e ["aspas simples"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#simple-blockquotes) (idem).

Eu acredito que *nidificação* seja a arte de se construir ninhos. A tradução correta seria *aninhamento*.

Comment: Afinal de contas, isto aqui não é o twitter :)

Comment: Na mesma parte da página: "Recue cinco espaços no total. **Os primeiros um** faz parte do designador de citação.". Correto seria substiuir o que deixei em negrito para "O primeiro" apenas.

Comment: Nossa @GuilhermeBernal "primeiro um" tem uma cara de tradução automática, né?

Comment: Bastante... "The first one" -> "Os primeiros um". Essa tradução está realmente sendo feita por [**humanos**](https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/captcha-conchords-robots.jpg)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que tenha encontrado todos. Infelizmente não faz parte do texto normal da Central de Ajuda, então teve que ser feito por override da tradução, que não mostra o todo (apenas trechos separados).

Vai pro ar com o próximo build.